# Cannot Archive in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

When I press "`Archive`" from "`Product`" in Xcode to Archive in order to submit my app to the Appstore, I get the message:

`unable to read input file '/Users/[my name]/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist': fopen(/Users/[my name]/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist, rb Name]/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist': fopen(/Users/[my name]/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist, rb): Operation not permitted (1) The error message "Operation not permitted (1)` appears and fails.

I am having trouble submitting my app to Apple because of this. This error message does not appear when I build in simulator or on a real device.

Today I received an email from Google Cloud Platform saying "`Your free trial has expired.`" I got an email saying I got this error after upgrading my GCP account, so the problem may be related to that, but I don't know why. The API key had changed with the upgrade, and I have updated the app to reflect the change.

How can I fix this problem?
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: are you able to run even? Clean build and try to re-run... For sure it won't work...

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to GCP account and API keys. API keys are just `Strings` for compiler without any expiry or other information.

As the error says "*unable to read input file '/Users/[my name]/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist'*". The builder while building the archive is unable to find the file at that current location. You have either deleted the file or moved to a new location.

To fix that, remove the old file from Xcode; re-download the plist file and drag drop to root of Xcode. Make sure to check on `Copy Items` when dialog appears.

Try archiving the project again.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and was able to Archive! Thank you!